# jquery to create array from form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been wrestling with this problem for a couple hours now.

Essentially, what I need to do is take the following or similar HTML:

```
<div id="excpdivs">
<div class="excpdiv" id="excpdiv0">
      Date: <input name="excp[0][date]">
      Open:  <input name="excp[0][open]">
      Close: <input name="excp[0][close]">
</div>
<div class="excpdiv" id="expdiv1">
      Date: <input name="excp[1][date]">
      Open:  <input name="excp[1][open]">
      Close: <input name="excp[1][close]">
</div>
```

and get an array similar to the following to a php script via AJAX:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2012-09-15
            [open] => 3:00
            [close] => 5:00
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2012-09-16
            [open] => 2:00
            [close] => 5:00
        )

)
```

My main problem is getting the values from the input elements. My latest attempt is the following:

```
    var results = [];
$(".excpdiv").each(function(){
    var item = {};
    var inpts = $(this).find("input");
    item.date = $(inpts.get(0)).val();
    item.open = $(inpts.get(1)).val();
    item.close = $(inpts.get(2)).val();
    results.push(item);
});
```

Am I on the right track or am I hopelessly lost?

Comment: Standard form submit, or Ajax? (Unrelated to your problem, you can say `inpts.eq(0).val()` instead of `$(inpts.get(0)).val()` - saves you having to create another jQuery object yourself.)

Comment: What is your issue? The code could be improved, but it's ok as is.

Comment: nnnnnn, Ajax instead of a standard form submit

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: James, nope, still not getting any values in to item.date, item.close, or item.open.  Thanks for your help though. I think I'm going to try and sleep on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple serialize.

From: api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
Example: Send form data using ajax requests


$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

Comment: `.serialize()` is just the method I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should do this instead

```
var results = [];
$(".excpdiv").each(function(){
    var item = {};
    var inpts = $(this).find("input");
    item.date = $(inpts)[0].val();
    item.open = $(inpts)[1].val();
    item.close = $(inpts)[2].val();
    results.push(item);
});
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. 

However, I'm getting the following error with your code:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'

Comment: lol i just now tried your own code it seems to work what exactly do you want from it??

Comment: Why are you calling `.val()` after using things like `[0]`? When you use `[0]`, you are getting the DOM element, which doesn't have jQuery methods...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery for this, the HTML markup you have will provide an array for php. Enclose the inputs in a form that posts to a php script to handle logic. Then you can access your information with:

```
$_POST['excp'][0]['date']
```

Comment: I should have specified that I want to send this via ajax instead of submitting the form directly to the php

Comment: Where did you specify that, its not even a tag. In any case use $.post to send a post request.http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/